# Como invocar o bootbox.js após gravação de dados no BD

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso mostrar uma caixa de mensagem usando o `bootbox.js` após gravação no banco de dados redirecionando o usuário?

Fiz um teste com o script a seguir, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
if($execCurso){ ?>
    <script>        
        $(document).on("load", ".alert", function(e) {
            bootbox.alert("Obrigado por se candidatar-se a essa vaga. Atualize seu currículo se achar necessário.", function() {
                var novaURL = "http://meuendereco/curriculo/Form.php";
                $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);                           
            });
        });         
    </script>

<?php   
}else{
    echo "Erro cadastrando";
    header("Location:home.php?m=0");
}
```

Fiz algumas consultas pelo Google mas não consegui encontrar a solução para o problema que tenho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de: `$(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);` tenta `location.href=novaURL`. Pra mim sempre funcionou assim.

Comment: Olá user3511079 o problema é que não estou conseguindo mostrar a mensagem.

Comment: @adventistapr No lugar de `$(document).on("load", ".alert", function(e) {` tenta `$(document).load(function(){`

Comment: Obrigado @Natanael Lopes, grande ajuda.